# Proceed to checkout buttons suddenly missing

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

Very strange issue, suddenly the proceed to checkout buttons are missing from the mini cart and the normal cart. When I check the code I can see below

Mini cart

```
<?php if($_cartQty && ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout() OR $this->getQuote()->getHasError())){ ?>
<button class="button btn-gotocart" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('View cart') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/') ?>')">
<?php echo $this->__('Winkelwagen') ?>
</button>
<button class="button btn-checkout" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Checkout') ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getCheckoutUrl() ?>')">
<?php echo $this->__('Afrekenen') ?>
</button>
<button class="button btn-update" type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update'); ?>" name="update_cart_action" value="update_qty" onclick="mincart.save();">
</button>
<?php  } ?>
```

Normal cart

```
<div class="totals">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
    <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
    <ul class="checkout-types">
    <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
        <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
        <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Only problem I now have is how to proceed with finding the issue :-(
When I manually go to the onestepcheckout page it works fine, I have shipping methods and payment methods available. When I remove

```
<?php if($_cartQty && ($this->isPossibleOnepageCheckout() OR $this->getQuote()->getHasError())){ ?>
```

the buttons show again

Comment: What happens when you click on it ? have you some error ?

Comment: No the problem is the buttons are missing.

Comment: can you share an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check these configurations:

1) your minimum order amount configuration, you can check this in :`Admin > System > Configuration > Sales > Minumum Order Amount`

2) Check if you have enabled the onepage checkout in `Admin > system > Configuration > checkout > Enabled onepage checkout`.

**Checkout/Helper/Data.php**

```
public function canOnepageCheckout()
{
    return (bool)Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/options/onepage_checkout_enabled');
}
```

Comment: Ok the webshop owner turned off the enabled onepage checkout, pffffff. Thanks a lot

Comment: you're welcome :)